# How to bind command in code-behind to view in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to execute a command in my code-behind (GenericReportingView.xaml.cs) from a button in my view (GenericReportingView.xaml)..

GenericReportingView.xaml:

```
 <Grid  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
     <Button Content="GetReport" Command="{Binding GetReportCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" />
 </Grid>
```

GenericReportingView.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class GenericReportingView
{
    private DelegateCommand _getReportCommand;
    public DelegateCommand GetReportCommand
    {
        get { return _getReportCommand ?? (_getReportCommand = new DelegateCommand(GetReport, (obj) => true)); }
    }

    public GenericReportingView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void GetReport(object obj)
    {
        //Do something..
    }
}
```

But the command isn't getting called..
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `GenericReportingView.xaml` is a UserControl, try `Command="{Binding GetReportCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`.

Comment: Binding uses the `.DataContext` property. You are trying to tell it to run the command at `Button.DataContext.GetReportCommand`, which doesn't exist. You can either set the View's `.DataContext` to itself in the constructor (OK for testing, but not recommended in most cases), change the source of the binding like [Ed suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110705/how-to-bind-command-in-code-behind-to-view-in-wpf#comment67492870_40110705), or just write a normal Click event like [Sam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40110960/302677) suggests below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be binding to properties in your code-behind. Bindings are usually used to link controls to properties in your view model (and it doesn't look like you have a view model in this case). Instead you could just use the click handler on the button to call your method:

GenericReportView.xaml:

```
<Grid  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <Button Content="GetReport" Click="GetReport" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" />
</Grid>
```

GenericReportView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class GenericReportingView
{
    public GenericReportingView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void GetReport(object obj, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something..
    }
}
```